# Combining observables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have two observables: LoadLocal and LoadServer. LoadLocal loads and returns an element from a local source and LoadServer fetches it from a server. I want to combine them into another observable: Load. I want Load to get the element from LoadLocal, and if it is null, I want to return the element from LoadServer. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

---

Details on the real scenario:

```
// loadLocal(id) gives me an observable that returns an asset from a local source
Func<Guid, IObservable<IAsset>> loadLocal = Observable.ToAsync<Guid, IAsset>(id => GetLocalAsset(id));

var svcClient = new ServiceClient<IDataService>();
var svc = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Request, Response>(svcClient.BeginInvoke, svcClient.EndInvoke);

// calling loadServer(id) gives me an observable that returns an asset from a server
var loadServer = id => from response in svc(new Request(id)) select response.Asset;

// so at this point i can call loadServer(id).Subscribe() to get an asset with specified id from the server, or I can call loadLocal(id).Subscribe() to get it from local source.
// however I want another observable that combines the two so I can do: load(id).Subscribe() that gets the asset from loadLocal(id) and if it is null it gets it from loadServer(id)
var load = ???
```

---

The following almost gives me the desired result, however both loadLocal(id) and loadServer(id) gets run. If loadLocal(id) returns an element, I don't want loadServer(id) to run.

```
var load = id => loadLocal(id).Zip(loadServer(id), (local, server) => local ?? server);
```

Comment: You don't "fetch" values when you use `IObservable`. Instead you get called (via `Subscribe`) when a new value is created. I really don't understand your question so maybe you can provide some more details about your observables and how they play together?

Comment: Updated the question with details on the real scenario.

Comment: I found a solution:

    var load = id => from localAsset in loadLocal(id)
                     from asset in (localAsset != null ? Observable.Return(localAsset) : loadServer(id))
                     select asset;

Comment: @Pking, then you should post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
loadLocal(id)
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Concat(Observable.Defer(() => loadServer(id)))
    .Take(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, besides the solution I mentioned in the comments of my original post, this also works.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that perhaps?

```
var load = LoadLocal.Zip(LoadServer, (local, server) => local ?? server);
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it and it works. However, It still tries to fetch elements from the server (LoadServer) even though LoadLocal returns elements (the point is to avoid unecessary round-trips to server if the element can be fetched locally).

Comment: @Pking, actually I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do... Martin's comment is correct: you don't fetch values from an observable.

Comment: Updated the question with details on the real scenario. It's very possible I'm approaching the problem in the wrong way. "fetch" refers to the work the observable itself does.